# Preg_replace и функция в поле смены текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здраствуйте.
Такое возможно

```
$text[1]=preg_replace('#<img src="([^\"]+)">#si', '[poster]'.urlencode('$1').'[/poster]',$text[1],1);
```

Вопрос простой, но в мануале не нашол овета, если ко знае просьба помочь.
Спасибо.

Comment: вы не можете сами проверить? Я не вижу тут ничего невозможного.

Answer (score 1):

если надо для всех найденных то [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
<?php
$input="test test test trESt";
$output=preg_replace_callback('/es/i',function($matches){
        return strrev($matches[0]);
    },$input);
echo $output;
```

http://ideone.com/n1MtxT